# Not able to invoke outlook OnSend Web Add in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

We recently have a Office 365 Outlook Web Add-in deployed. The web Add-in is hosted on URL and Outlook Web App(OWA) works fine while invoked from google chrome and Microsoft edge. While in IE11 we are facing the below issues where in the JS/CSS files are being aborted while invoked via OWA , but when we load the URL directly via IE11 browsers , everything works fine.

Request your help if any of you faced similar issues with IE11.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any errors in the console? What is the status code for those files in network tab? check whether those files are using HTTP protocols or not. If so than try to use HTTPS protocol and make a test. Let us know about your testing results.

Comment: Hi Deepak ,there are no errors on console and all are using HTTPS protocol only. There are no status code.. on HTTP Watch it says aborted. And this issue occurs only in IE11 and not on chrome or Edge.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook/Office-365-Outlook-Web-Addin-Not-Working-on-IE-11/m-p/905623#M3455 has the screenshots of HTTPWatch

Comment: Try to enable 'Allow data sources across domains' option in internet options to see whether it helps to fix this issue. If issue persist than try to lower down the security settings for testing purpose and check the issue again.

Comment: I've tried all settings.. Even made the Internet Zone security level to the lowest possible level and still OWA aborts all JS/CSS calls. But If I launch the URL directly on IE11 everything works fine with default IE settings , but via OWA the same URL doesnt work.

Comment: Please let us know about the exact IE version and OS build. If possible than try to provide any sample code to produce the issue. We will try to test the issue to check the result. It can give some idea about the issue.

Comment: IE Version : 11.805.17763 , OS: Windows 10.... Basically my code is an Office 365 Outlook Web Add in that is hosted on https://xxx.abc.com ... This web add in is called when ever an user drafts a mail on OWA and click on Send. The index page of the web app is 200 OK , while the JS/CSS that are added get aborted.

Comment: Can you please share your sample code to reproduce the issue.